# How to define the output filename based on input rvtFile in Activity?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I've created activity , and my output file name is always result.zip.
I put my result into the bucket. When i post few workitems, everytime rezult.zip file overrides.

Is it possible to define the output file name based in inputFileName like var $rvtFile?

I've tried in my appbundle to create folder for saving results based on Document Title without extension, but i can't get those file with activity.

```
"parameters": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Input Revit model",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "$(rvtFile)"
        },
       "resultifc": {
            "zip": true,
            "verb": "put",
            "description": "Output Ifc model",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "result"
        }
      }
```

I'd like to have something like :
localName :$"(rvtFile)_result"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the result file you save in your addin code needs to be hardcoded (`result.zip`), note that you may always create a custom output signed URL with appropriate file location. For example:

*workitem 1:*

```
"resultifc": {
   "url": https://myhostname/filename.zip
}
```

*workitem 2:*

```
"resultifc": {
   "url": https://myhostname/othername.zip
}
```

Currently we do not support variable expansion of the kind:

```
localName :$"(rvtFile)_result"
```

But here is something else that you might consider using:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/field-guide/#variable-expansion

You can dynamically insert the work item id in your output file url.

Comment: I want to save my result.zip in the bucket, so i need to know the exact filename

Comment: At the time of posting the workitem, you know the name of the input file. So you should be able to generate the output location based on the name of the input file. Will that help?

Comment: I have some outputs. Based on this post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-generate-dynamic-number-output-design-automation-revit-v3
i create a folder with name result,and it is zipped.
If i want to put those result.zip into the bucket i can't rename it

Comment: My suggestion would be to keep most of it same. ie. continue to keep the hardcoded folder name `result` in your app bundle. Keep the activity definition same `localName = result`. 

While posting the workitem, you know the name of the input file. Generate the output file location url based on that name. For eg if your input url is `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybuckect/inputs/myfile.rvt`, generate the output url yourself as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybuckect/outputs/results_myfile.zip`.

Comment: are you uploading to an s3 bucket or oss? Both should allow you to generate the object at a location of your choice within the bucket.